# Connecting AKNodes after init

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

Easy to connect a synth to a AudioKit compressor like...

```
compressor = AKCompressor(akMidiSampler)
```

Instead of this I need to connect after the initializer...

```
 compressor = AKCompressor()
 ...
```

How can I connect this AKMidiSampler to the compressor after the initializer ?

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

`akMidiSampler.connect(to: compressor)` and `akMidiSampler >>> compressor`

`>>>` is a custom operator that calls `connect(to:)`

Comment: Something is not working here. I get sound with this: compressor = AKCompressor(akMidiSampler) . Silence with: compressor = AKCompressor() ; akMidiSampler >>> compressor ... Any ideas ?

Comment: After some testings, I realized that connecting after init this way works with other effects, Delay, Reverb, etc... But not for AKCompressor. Is it a bug ? Any idea ?

Comment: It is(was) a bug, thanks! https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/pull/1281